# Docker push - Enviar a imagem para o Docker Hub

Tags: docker

tudo bem?

Alguém consegue me ajudar no seguinte problema?

Primeramente realizei o login no Docker, executando o comando:

```
$ docker login
```

Inclui o usuário e senha cadastrado, porém estou com problemas no momento de enviar uma image para o Docker Hub. Quando executo o seguinte comando:

```
$ docker push projetofinal2_web
```

O seguinte erro ocorre:

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/library/projetofinal2_web]
6e2e1155d419: Preparing 
1cb633a23e71: Preparing 
6b91dd5a05f0: Preparing 
7dc8d752af64: Preparing 
af8b16133eb3: Preparing 
27951393f8e7: Waiting 
f89067d6e30e: Waiting 
5129f19da2c9: Waiting 
34929ec591c4: Waiting 
e02b32b1ff99: Waiting 
f75e64f96dbc: Waiting 
8f7ee6d76fd9: Waiting 
c23711a84ad4: Waiting 
90d1009ce6fe: Waiting 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Verifiquei que a image projetofinal2_web realmente existe utilizando o comando:

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
projetofinal2_web   latest              c27ee5582377        17 minutes ago      983MB
<none>              <none>              082bd1514477        28 hours ago        918MB
<none>              <none>              148f5843aabb        2 days ago          981MB
<none>              <none>              ac09ab02e2f3        2 days ago          981MB
postgres            latest              f9b577fb1ed6        6 days ago          311MB
python              3.6.7               1ec4d11819ad        2 weeks ago         918MB
```

Projeto no GitHub: https://github.com/gabrieldeoliveiraestevam/projeto?files=1

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a [documentação](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#pushing-a-repository-image-to-docker-hub):

> To push a repository to the Docker Hub, you need to name your local image using your Docker Hub username, and the repository name that you created in the previous step [...]

Você precisar criar uma `tag` para a usa imagem antes de subir:

- No momento do *build*: `$ docker build -t <hub-user>/<repo-name>[:<tag>]`  **ou**
- Imagem já criada: `$ docker tag <existing-image> <hub-user>/<repo-name>[:<tag>]`

E depois para subir pro repositório remoto:

```
$ docker push <hub-user>/<repo-name>:<tag>
```

Onde:

- `hub-user`: seu usuário no DockerHub
- `repo-name`: o nome do repositório remoto no DockerHub
- `existing-image`: image já construída
- `tag`: *tag* para a imagem (e.g v1.0)

**E pro seu caso, faria assim, por exemplo:**

1. Adicionar a *tag* na sua imagem:

   `$ docker tag projetofinal2_web:latest <seu_usuario_dockerhub>/<seu_repo_dockerhub>:v1.0`
2. E depois fazer o *push*:

   `$ docker push <seu_usuario-dockerhub>/<seu_repo_dockerhub:v0.1`